# Can node refferences be automatically resolved in a view?

Tags: views

We are using drupal for data management for a web application. We're using the web-service api to get data from drupal views and use it on our app.

We are completely depended on views fetched via the web service.

When fetching a view, we would like to get all it's references already resolved. So if I have entity A with references to B and C, it would be great to get entity A with the data of B and C as well, not just the node ids.

Can such a thing be achieved via the web-service api?

Update:

After using relationships and a table list that can have reference node fields, I am able to see the aggregated data from B and C. I have the list of A type entities, with data from B and C, but when I request this data from the /webservice/views/MyView api I am not able to see the newly formatted data. I get the same old result with the target_ids instead of the fields that I chose in the table list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views *relationships* are used to bring in data from referenced nodes. From your view's administrative page, expand the `Advanced` section and add a relationship. Select the appropriate node/entity reference field that bridges your nodes. Now you can add fields to your view and configure them to use your relationship, which will pull in *any* data from the *referenced* entities/nodes. At this point your view should contain data you want, making it available to the web service.

Comment: Will check it out monday and see how it works. I'm hoping this will be a lot faster than making n additional requests from our app to resolve n references of a node.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. I'm looking at the view configuration right now. The advanced panel is a bit confusing. I have "A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_challenge_category" and "A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_challenge_category" as two possible references and no explanation of what one means compared to the other. I am also not able to use view fields because I am using formatted list which says "The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.".

Comment: updated my question, I would appreciate it if you could take another look.

Comment: will choose your answer as the best one. I figured it out for normal references, but I still have an issue with lists of references. I opened another question for that. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115309/is-there-a-way-to-resolve-a-list-of-references-in-a-view-without-cloning-entire

Answer (score 1):

Link Swanson's answer above should work, except for in some cases where you may actually need the reverse relationship (depending upon how the nodes relate to one another).

If the relationship between entity A and entity B is created by a node reference field on entity A that pulls in entity B, then you can probably just use a regular relationship.

But if the relationship between the two is from entity B pointing to entity A, and especially if your view pulls in entity A, you will most likely need a reverse relationship.

You would add the reverse relationship in the same place that Link Swanson described. It's just a different configuration option.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out monday. This is actually a problem we had this sprint... hopefully this will solve it :)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how a reverse relationship should be set up?

Comment: OK, so on one of my projects we have a content type call "proposal" and proposals are reviewed by blind peer reviewers. We use node reference url (https://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) as a field on the second content type called "review" to create the relationship between the two nodes.

Comment: Next, I want to show a list of all proposals and the result of their review. So I start by creating a view that filters for the content type proposal. Then, I create a reverse relationship using the node reference field so that I can pull in data from the review such as whether the reviewer recommended that the proposal be accepted or rejected and any comments. To pull in the fields from the review, I add the field and select the relationship from the dropdown in the field settings. Does this help?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. Will think this thru and see if I can do the same on the project that I'm working on. Much appreciated! :)