# Is there a way to resolve a list of references in a view without cloning entire rows of data?

Tags: views

I'm playing around with the drupal views and reference relationships. I have an entity of type A that has a reference to entity of type B, and a list of references to entities of type C. Reached this point thanks to : [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/can-node-refferences-be-automatically-resolved-in-a-view)

Using views -> advanced -> relationships I can create a relationship to B and then add the fields that I want from B in the view of A. However, when doing the same thing for the list of C, I am seeing the same entity of type A repeated as many times as there are references to the entity of type C.

Is there a way to have the list of C entities without the duplication behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use the results of the query, you could use a GROUPBY option within the Views config.
Find the GROUPING options by clicking on the word "Settings" under FORMAT. The link for "Settings" appears to the right of the pipe symbol which separates the chosen format from the "Settings" link.
Once you do this, it should remove the duplicates.